# SQL Table-Creation: AS Uppercase declaration not functioning [SQL]

Tags: sql, sapui5, hana

I do have the following Issue: When creating a new Table:

```
COLUMN TABLE "Example"( 
"ID"   INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL,
"Name" NVARCHAR(10),
"NameUpperCase"   NVARCHAR(50) AS UPPER("Name"),
"IDUpperCase"   NVARCHAR(15) AS UPPER("ID"),
 PRIMARY KEY (   
"ID"
 )
) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE ;
```

i am met with the issue that `AS is not supported`. For a very long time it did work, now it seemingly doesn't.

**Question:** How to solve that?

Comment: What is `COLUMN TABLE`?  Is the statement missing a `CREATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you missed adding 'CREATE' before :)

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "Example"( 
"ID"   INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL,
"Name" NVARCHAR(10),
"NameUpperCase"   NVARCHAR(50) AS UPPER("Name"),
"IDUpperCase"   NVARCHAR(15) AS UPPER("ID"),
 PRIMARY KEY (   
"ID"
)) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE ;
```